# Why does psql return float4 numbers with only 3 decimals

Tags: database, postgresql, floating-point, precision, psql

I am using psql to interact with a postgresql database, I executed my query

```
select latitude, longitude from myschema.mytable order by longitude limit 10;
```

The output

```
 latitude | longitude 
----------+-----------
  1.30806 |   103.631
  1.30805 |   103.631
  1.30807 |   103.632
  1.31557 |   103.632
  1.31407 |   103.633
  1.31644 |   103.635
  1.31644 |   103.635
  1.34128 |   103.636
  1.32722 |   103.678
  1.32611 |   103.678
(10 rows)
```

But when I execute the same query in dbeaver, I see

[image]

The column types of latitude and longitude are both float4

Three questions, please.

1. Why psql gives me different numbers of decimals for latitude and longitude columns while they are of both float4
2. Why doesn't psql show me all the decimals, esp. for the longitude column?
3. float4 is as precise to as to the 6th decimal, is that right?

Comment: Related: [Converting float4 to numeric in PostgreSQL is rounding the values](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/219276/2037).

Comment: You can use a POINT type which stores lat/lon. Or install the PostGIS extension and use the GEOGRAPHY type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the doc closely, https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/datatype-numeric.html

I think the following points explain the behaviors.

- The **scale** of a numeric is the count of decimal digits in the fractional part, to the right of the decimal point.
- The **precision** of a numeric is the total count of significant digits in the whole number, that is, the number of digits to both sides of the decimal point.
- On most platforms, the real (4 bytes, I suppose it's float4) type has a range of at least 1E-37 to 1E+37 with a precision of at least **6 decimal digits**.
- The double precision (8 bytes, float8) type typically has a range of around 1E-307 to 1E+308 with a precision of at least 15 digits.

So for `float4` column type, I think what's after the 6th digit may not be reliable.

Comment: Do you know the reason why sql output values that have more than 6 dicimal digits?

Comment: Check the link in the answer

Comment: i couldnt find the answer. so, you dont know  the answer?  it depend on the platform?